# Does Delphi String-variant comparison use loInvariantLocale? How to locally enable loUserLocale instead?

Tags: sorting, delphi, comparator, variant, tcxgrid

My problem arises from DevExpress TcxGrid default comparison (used for the sorting of data), which boils down to the code (implemented in `cxVariants.pas`):

```
  if VarIsEmpty(V1) then
    if VarIsEmpty(V2) then
      Result := 0
    else
      Result := -1
  else
    if VarIsEmpty(V2) then
      Result := 1
    else
      if V1 = V2 then
        Result := 0
      else
        if V1 < V2 then
          Result := -1
        else
          Result := 1;
```

My tests assure that `V1 < V2` works as `CompareStr(V1, V2, loInvariantLocale)`, but usually one would like that `V1 < V2` should work as `CompareStr(V1, V2, loUserLocale)`.

And this is also reflected in the sorting results of cxGrid: usually Eastern European languages expect that diacritical characters follow immediately their original characters, but `loInvariantLocal` puts all the diacritical characters at the end of all non-diacritical characters. One expects orders `aā .. zž`, but cxGrid sorts like `a .. z, ā .. ž`.

So: **is it possible to ask some code fragment to use `loUserLocale` for variant comparison?**

Of course, I will just override `cxGrid.cxGridDBTableView.Controller.OnCompare()`, but I am a bit uneasy about the general situation whether I can or I can not affect variant comprison.

Comment: The default is sort by the ordinal values of the characters. Enable `cxGrid1DBTableView1.DataController.Options.dcoAnsiSort` to do it based on locale.

Comment: Huh, thx @Brian - this is really cool, I was not aware of that!

Comment: @Brian that should be posted as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is to compare the ordinal values of the characters. To compare based on the locale enable the DataController's option dcoAnsiSort (`cxGrid1DBTableView1.DataController.Options.dcoAnsiSort`).

> **dcoAnsiSort**
>
> If active, a grid control uses Windows locale settings to sort
> records. This option is useful when grid cells contain native language
> text.
>
> Otherwise, strings are compared based on the 8-bit ordinal value of each character.

The docs are a bit dated - for wide characters the 16-bit ordinal values are compared. (Ref:[TcxDataControllerOption Enum](https://docs.devexpress.com/VCL/cxCustomData.TcxDataControllerOption#remarks))